# Define custom Android components using short namespace?

Tags: android

Working on my first Android application. I'm wondering if there's a way to use the xmlns in the markup in any way. In Flex, for example, I can define a namespace:

```
<mx:VBox xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    xmlns:cb="com.typeoneerror.apps.app.views.components.*">
    <cb:CustomComponent paramName="demo"></cb:CustomComponent>
</mx:VBox>
```

Android seems to be slightly different. You use the namespace when defining params but not the tag itself. This is a bit wordy to me, so I'm wondering if there's a way to configure or change this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:cb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.typeoneerror.apps.app">
    <com.typeoneerror.apps.app.views.components.CustomComponent cb:paramName="demo"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'd like to use

```
<cb:CustomComponent cb:paramName="demo"></cb:CustomComponent>
```

Possible?

Comment: Are you using Flex to build your Android application?  If so, the same approach you are using w/in Flex should work w/ Flex /AIR for android.

Comment: It's a native app, Flextras. I'm just looking for a similar workflow as Flex as I'm not super familiar with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry. The element name is a Java class name, and in the case of custom widgets, is a fully-qualified class name.

I have seen some syntax where the element name is `View` and there is a `class` attribute with the widget's class name. I can't find that in the docs and don't have an sample available, though.

Comment: The class attribute was an earlier way to define a custom view. It's still supported by the layout parser, but the documented syntax is a lot clearer, I think.

Comment: I agree, Ted. Thanks for the info, folks.